# Is there an easy way to find the source mk file for a specific target?

Tags: gnu-make

I am using an environment that consists of many makefiles scattered across the system.  If I am given a specific target, I'd like to find the actual makefile where that target is defined without manually scanning each file looking for include statements recursively.
Does gnu-make have any functionality that can tell you the source file of the target?  Or has anyone written a script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run GNU make with `-p` option to dump parsed Makefile. Each defined target and each resolved implicit rule will be there, including its location in a file, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
include other.mk

all: foo.o

$ cat other.mk
%.o:
        @echo Building $@
```

Output (note it contains both implicit rule and targets expanded from that rule):

```
$ make -r -p
...
%.o:
#  recipe to execute (from 'other.mk', line 2):
        @echo Building $@
...
foo.o:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'foo'
#  File does not exist.
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := foo.o
# automatic
# % :=
# automatic
# * := foo
# automatic
# + :=
# automatic
# | :=
# automatic
# < :=
# automatic
# ^ :=
# automatic
# ? :=
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/12=8%
#  recipe to execute (from 'other.mk', line 2):
        @echo Building $@
...
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's much easier and also much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "looking for include statements" to identify the makefile where a specific target is made.
Aside from that, it depends on whether the targets are named explicitly or a pattern rule is used. In the latter case it can be impossible to find the relevant makefile as there is not necessarily any connection up until the invocation of `make` between a target and its prerequisites - things like `VPATH` or the delegation to a sub makefile with change of working directory, searching sources by hand (per `wildcard`) may all influence which targets are made where. That said, most makefile hierarchies are not so complicated to understand otherwise they would never have gotten there. You may try to search for the naming of a target in a dependency file. The other possibility is to do a `make --dry-run` or even a `make --always-make` and look at the log output.

Comment: Thanks. The primary "Makefile" has "include" and "-include" statements to include other makefiles.  Those files also have "include" statements and so forth.  The hierarchy actually is too complicated to understand and to make matters worse, these file paths are often include environment variables.  I am sure this was never the intention of the creators of make, and there are much better tools out there, but that ship has sailed.  And yes most targets use a pattern rule as well, so grepping for the target doesn't work even if I did know the location of all the makefiles.

Comment: @JDWK I feel your pain - does evaluating the build log work in your case? While I understand that the old makefile is a mess, getting a clean build from scratch is sometimes surprisingly simple, iff (if and only if) the previous one used a single mechanism to connect targets with recipes. The convoluted output of everything but the kitchen sink may be scary but if the underlying technique always is sg. like "take env variable which is named like target and use the non-documented file structure of target" then not all hope is lost.

Comment: Do you mean just build the target with "make -d -n my_target" and parse the output?

Comment: Yes. Be sure to build from a clean state so no target is omitted.